# XQuery SQL Extract text value from a child element of a specific node

Tags: sql, xml, xquery, xsql

I'm struggling with the following situation:  I need to extract that '10000' after

```
...name="stateid"> <from>10000</from>
```

I've managed to extract some that I need from the first node audittrail

```
SELECT ref.value ('@datetime', 'nvarchar(364)') as [LastTimeActioned],
ref.value ('@changedby', 'nvarchar(364)') as [Actioned_By]
FROM Audit 
CROSS APPLY audit.Xml.nodes ('/audittrail') R(ref)


<audittrail id="137943" datetime="29-Feb-2016 15:42:06" changedby="quality" type="update">
   <fields>
     <field id="10022" name="Content Control">
      <mergedValue>dsad</mergedValue>
      <from />
      <to>dsad</to>
     </field>
     <field id="10027" name="Document Controller">
      <mergedValue>quality</mergedValue>
      <from />
      <to>quality</to>
    </field>
    <field id="10028" name="Document Owner">
      <mergedValue>quality</mergedValue>
      <from />
      <to>quality</to>
    </field>
    <field id="10029" name="Document Type">
      <mergedValue>Contract/Agreement</mergedValue>
      <from />
      <to>Contract/Agreement</to>
    </field>
    <field id="10067" name="StateId">
      <from>10000</from>
      <to>10000</to>
    </field>
    ....
  </fields>
</audittrail>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the Xpath:

```
 (fields/field[@name="StateId"]/from)[1]
```

i.e. Find me the "fields/field" element with the attribute name of value `StateId`, and select the contents of the immediate child `from` element:

```
SELECT 
   ref.value ('@datetime', 'nvarchar(364)') as [LastTimeActioned],
   ref.value ('@changedby', 'nvarchar(364)') as [Actioned_By],
   ref.value ('(fields/field[@name="StateId"]/from)[1]', 'integer') as StateIdFrom
FROM Audit 
CROSS APPLY audit.Xml.nodes ('/audittrail') R(ref)
```

[SqlFiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bcd7ae/7)

Note that you need to [explicitly select the first text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079628/what-is-the-significance-of-1-in-xquery) result in XQuery (hence the extra parenthesis() and [1])

More technically correctly, you could also restrict the selection to the `text()` of the child `from`, i.e.:

```
(fields/field[@name="StateId"]/from/text())[1]
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart, It's works like a treat.  By the way is it possible to use value of the StateIdFrom Column e.g inner join it to another table which contains that value ?

Comment: Yes - sure - suggest you wrap up the above query into a Derived Table Or Cte and then Join. [Example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bcd7ae/9)

Comment: Thanks Stuart!! I've created a view of the first part so then I can finish querying the rest of the data to be used in a report.